# How to truncate org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.BadCredentialsAuthenticationException Stack trace in log file?

Tags: log4j, cas

I'm using CAS for single signon solution, My log(log4j version 1.2.15) file completely fills with the Exception(org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.BadCredentialsAuthenticationException)
Stack trace when User enters invalid login credentials.

Is there a solution to trim the Stack trace in CAS or Java?

I can't use log4j EnhancePatternLayout to achieve this as it requires log4j version 1.2.16

Any suggestions around this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used CAS.  However, the way that I've gotten around similar problems in the past is by suppressing log messages from the offending class.  For example, if you're using a log4j.properties file, insert this line:

```
log4j.logger.com.jasig.cas.WhateverClassLogsTheException=OFF
```

Note that you will need to suppress messages from the class that throws the exception, not the exception class itself.  Also, you can also use FATAL or other values to ensure that only log messages that are at or above the given level are logged.  See [the Log4J docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) for more information.

Note that this will suppress *all* messages from that class, not just the particular log message that produces that exception.

Comment: But I want first 2 lines of the Exception to be logged in Log file.

Comment: In that case, you will probably need to write a custom Appender implementation (probably subclassing WriterAppender or AppenderSkeleton).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is CAS is passing Exception object to Log4j,so I did comment that line in my overlayed class. BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.java